# How to securely serve S3 files without using Signed URL?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am no AWS expert so I am hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.

I have files (images specifically) stored in a S3 bucket, and I need to display these images in a KML file, which is to be delivered to a client. The image URL would go into a  HTML tag. (KML allows the ability to embed HTML code as part of its content, FYI.) However, these images cannot be publicly accessible (as it is part of a confidential project) and should only be accessible using a special URL.

I have explored the Cloudfront option a little bit and from my understanding, Signed URL with Cloudfront will not work since there is an expire date on it, which does not work with a client, given that the max expire date is 7 days I heard. Also, is it even possible to use a signed URL as the src for a ?

And signed cookies would not work too since Google Earth (which opens KML files) does not actually use an integrate web browser when rendering the HTML code.

I do run a Python script to generate this KML file, so it is possible for me to create signed URL, but unfortunately I don't think signed URL would help with the problem as I had described above.

Any ideas or suggestions on how I can tackle this? Is there a way where the S3 or Cloudfront file URL includes a key in there that doesn't expire?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your requirement to grant only a single third-party client to access these images securely without any expiry date for the URLs? And how likely a new client joins in with separate permission (Is this possible)?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront can be used to generate signed urls, which allows you to set your own expiration date which can extend up to years.

> You can also distribute private content using a signed URL that is
>   valid for a longer time, possibly for years.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html#private-content-overview-choosing-duration

According to AWS it is a good practice to allow access to the resources in S3 through CloudFront, instead of exposing S3 urls directly. You can read through this documentation for more information. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

And finally the answer to your question

*Is it even possible to use a signed URL as the src for a?*

Yes, after all it is a just a url with some extra characters.